# How would this be written without using yield?

Tags: python, yield, pi

I've tried and failed multiple times trying to replace yield, but I don't seem to be successful, the goal is to have the same function, without yield.

```
def calcPi(limit):  # Generator function
    """
    Prints out the digits of PI
    until it reaches the given limit
    """

    q = 1
    r = 0
    t = 1
    k = 1
    n = 3
    l = 3

    decimal = limit
    counter = 0

    while counter != decimal + 1:
        if 4 * q + r - t < n * t:
            # yield digit
            yield n
            # insert period after first digit
            if counter == 0:
                yield '.'
            # end
            if decimal == counter:
                print('')
                break
            counter += 1
            nr = 10 * (r - n * t)
            n = ((10 * (3 * q + r)) // t) - 10 * n
            q *= 10
            r = nr
        else:
            nr = (2 * q + r) * l
            nn = (q * (7 * k) + 2 + (r * l)) // (t * l)
            q *= k
            t *= l
            l += 2
            k += 1
            n = nn
            r = nr
```

Added the full function as people were asking for it in the comments,

Comment: When you post code to stackoverflow, people should be able to run it. This code is full of undefined variables and seems to be extracted from a function (the only place `yield` works). You should either simplify it to remove all code unnecessary for the problem (preferable) or define the variables so you can post a desired output given the input.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to have the values that you yield collected in a list instead?

Comment: Added the full function, yes I want the values collected in a list instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I've tried and failed multiple times trying to replace yield, but I don't seem to be successful" How did you try? What went wrong when you tried that? "yes I want the values collected in a list instead" Okay, so why is this difficult? What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? What should the list contain initially? What should happen to the list each time, instead of `yield`ing? It's not clear why or how there is an actual question here.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani rather, `yield` *needs to be* inside a *function* - but it certainly can be inside a `while` loop, inside that function.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am not opposed to what you said, nor my previous comment. But yeah, it looks like my comment was:)) I didn't mean it, so I'll delete it. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Instead of yielding values to be printed elsewhere, the function could print them directly.  (And in fact the docstring claims to do that already...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a list and collect the digits:

```py
def calcPi(limit):  # Generator function
    """
    Collects the digits of PI
    until it reaches the given limit
    """
    pi = []
    ...

    while ...:
        ...
        # yield n
        pi.append(n)
        ...
            #break
            return pi
```